# Derivation of the identity $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}=4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vector-analysis, dirac-delta, divergence-operator

Let $\vec r=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$ a position vector and $\delta^3(\vec{r})=\delta (x)\delta (y)\delta (z)$ is the [tree-dimensional Dirac's delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Generalizations), undertood in the sense of distributions (it is zero at all points except at the origin, where it equals infinite). I'm looking for a proof of the following identity,

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}=4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r})$$

How could it be derived?

Comment: The function is not even defined at $r=0$

Comment: I suspect this is understood in the sense of Distributions ? Btw, the Dirac delta is *not* a function, nor one that equals infinity at the origin. Have a quick read at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) first in case you're confused :)

Comment: Yes, Dirac's delta is indeed understood here in the sense of distributions, although it is usually called (incorrectly) a function.

Comment: Show that $\Delta\frac1r=0$ away from the origin, then apply the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{A}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\phi\vec{A})-\vec{\nabla}\phi\cdot\vec{A}$, we want to prove scalar test functions $f$ satisfy$$\int_\Omega\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\cdot\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}=-4\pi f(\vec{0}),$$where $\Omega$ denotes $3$-dimensional space, which we'll parameterize with spherical polar coordinates so the integral is$$4\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\cdot\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{r})r^2dr=4\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}dr=-4\pi f(\vec{0}).$$